# Get multiple items of multiple apps in podio api

Tags: podio

Can i  retrieve all the items in my filter which is under multiple apps which has same app name in podio api.

Example scenario:
I have two work space. Both work space have Deliverable app. I want to get all items in Deliverable from both work space, and i want to filter through it.

I can get items in an app by :

```
PodioItem::filter( $app_id, $attributes = array(), $options = array() );
```

is there a way like:

```
PodioItems::filter(array($multiple_app_id), $attributes = array(), $options = array() );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The API filter operation doesn't support passing multiple app ids. You'll have to make a separate call for each app that you'd like to retrieve items, regardless of the workspace.